# How to open a resource pdf file in its native browser from within a c# application?

Tags: c#, file, pdf, resources

I have a pdf file for example C:\myfile.Pdf

Currently I can launch the file from C# code using

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\myfile.pdf")

However i will prefer to embed this file as a resource.

How do i accomplish the same result.
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(nameof(MyNamespace.Properties.Resources.myfile)));//This will not work

Comment: You'll probably need to extract it to a temporary file, use `Process.Start`, wait for it to exit, then delete the temporary file. The user's default PDF reader isn't going to know how to open PDF's from any place which isn't a file

Comment: Associated programs are expecting file as input. If you are running something directly, then you can theoretically use that software API or command parameters (assuming they are provided) to pass input differently.

Answer (score 0):

If I copy the pdf file into the projects Bin\Release folder then I can simply use the same line of code above.